# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0 after updating Newtonsoft.Json version in project

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, dependencies

I made some changes to my project that required updating Newtonsoft to version 10.0.2. My project runs fine locally, but when I try to build it on my testing environment through Jenkins, the build is failing and the site is throwing a 500 error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

When I ran nuget to install packages, changes to Newtonsoft.Json were made in three files: src/MySite.Library/packages.config, web/Website/packages.config, and web/Website/MySite.csproj:

packages.config:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

csproj:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
```

I tried modifying the web.config to see if that would fix the 500 error, since I noticed that it was still using the old version:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I changed this to

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Before I changed the web.config, the error said "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0". When I changed the config to 10.0.2, it now says "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0"

Comment: How are you publishing to your test environment? I've found that the "delete all files" option on publish is set to No, some things that should be overwritten aren't which causes me to have to manually delete them (or everything) and republish so that the needed files get sent over.

Comment: perhaps put Jenkins in the tags and the title.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I have hit before.  Newtonsoft never actually puts the minor version numbers in their assembles.  Just change your new binding redirect to be:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran `Update-Package –reinstall Newtonsoft.Json`, and that updated several app.config files that didn't get changed previously. Once I checked in the updated app.config files with the newer Newtonsoft.Json versions, the build succeeded.